# Deshabilitar un list group

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo un list group como en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero deshabilitarlo cuando se toque el boton "Editar" usando el siguiente codigo, pero cuando lo hago los botones siguen siendo "clickiables", como puedo deshabilitarlo correctamente?, Gracias

**Codigo para deshabilitar list group**

```
$(document).on('click', '.editRuta', function () {
    $(".list_of_items").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay una forma muy sencilla que yo uso para deshabilitar y lo consigo añadiendo una propiedad en css cuando lo estés editando.

```
$(document).on('click', '.editRuta', function () {
    $(".list_of_items").addClass("desabilitado");
});
```

Y en el CSS, puedes agregar algo como:

```
.deshabilitado{
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Con opacity haces que cualquier cosa se vea semitransparente (con valores del 1 al 0) y con `pointer events`, cancelas el `clic` en ese elemento. Ahora puedes agregar más elementos inhabilitantes de acciones como:

```
.deshabilitado{
  position: relative;
}

.deshabilitado::before{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
}
```

Con lo anterior creas un pseudo elemento que cubre todo el elemento y no permite ninguna interacción sobre este.

Puedes combinar esta alternativa con la anterior e incluso, puedes añadir un efecto (totalmente opcional) para que se vea vuelva todo gris, así:

```
.deshabilitado{
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: relative;
  filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

Aquí una demo, de las 3 opciones, para que veas como queda:

```js
$(".check").click(function () {
    $("ul").toggleClass("deshabilitado");
    $(this).toggleClass("activado");
});
```

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0;}

body{ font-family: calibri, sans-serif; padding-top: 2.5em;}

h3{
  padding: 1em 1em .5em;
  font-size: 0.6em;
}

label{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 1em;
  left: 1em;
  background: pink;
}

.activado{
  background: cyan;
}

ul{
 color: #555;
 font-size: 0.8em;
}

li{
 border: 1px solid lightgray;
 padding: 0.3em 1em;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

span{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: center;
}

button, label{
  border-radius: .5em;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: center;
  padding: 0.3em 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  box-shadow: 
    inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(100,0,0,.3),
    inset 0 -2px 0 0 rgba(100,0,0,.3);
  border: none;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  cursor: pointer;
}

li:first-child button{
  background-color: yellow;
}
li:last-child button{
  background-color: crimson;
}

.deshabilitado{
  transition: all ease .3s;
}

.deshabilitado.tipo1{
  opacity: 0.6;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.deshabilitado.tipo2{
  position: relative;
}

.deshabilitado.tipo2::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.6)
}

.deshabilitado.tipo3{
  filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="check">deshabilitar</label>
<h3>Normal</h3>
<ul>
  <li>
  <span>Texto ejemplo</span> <button>Boton</button>
  </li>
  <li>
  <span>Texto ejemplo</span> <button>Boton</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<h3>Disabilitado Ej: 1</h3>
<ul class="tipo1">
  <li>
  <span>Texto ejemplo</span> <button>Boton</button>
  </li>
  <li>
  <span>Texto ejemplo</span> <button>Boton</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<h3>Disabilitado Ej: 2 con seudoelemento</h3>
<ul class="tipo2">
  <li>
  <span>Texto ejemplo</span> <button>Boton</button>
  </li>
  <li>
  <span>Texto ejemplo</span> <button>Boton</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<h3>Disabilitado Ej: 3 combinado</h3>
<ul class="tipo1 tipo2 tipo3">
  <li>
  <span>Texto ejemplo</span> <button>Boton</button>
  </li>
  <li>
  <span>Texto ejemplo</span> <button>Boton</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**¿Era lo que buscabas?** No dudes en escribirme por si tienes otra duda.

---

### Actualizado

Ejemplo actualizado para usar dos botones, en vez de uno:

En un botón, añades la clase:

```
$("ul").addClass("deshabilitado");
```

Y en el otro, la remueves:

```
$("ul").removeClass("deshabilitado");
```

Mira este ejemplo:

```js
$(".deshabilita").click(function () {
    $("ul").addClass("deshabilitado");
});

$(".habilita").click(function () {
    $("ul").removeClass("deshabilitado");
});
```

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0;}

body{ font-family: calibri, sans-serif; padding-top: 2.5em;}

h3{
  padding: 1em 1em .5em;
  font-size: 0.6em;
}

div{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 1em;
  left: 1em;
}

label{  outline-color: transparent; }
label:focus{ background: cyan; }

.habilita{
  background: whitesmoke;
}

.deshabilita{
  background: pink;
}

ul{
 color: #555;
 font-size: 0.8em;
}

li{
 border: 1px solid lightgray;
 padding: 0.3em 1em;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

span{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: center;
}

button, label{
  border-radius: .5em;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: center;
  padding: 0.3em 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  box-shadow: 
    inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(100,0,0,.3),
    inset 0 -2px 0 0 rgba(100,0,0,.3);
  border: none;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  cursor: pointer;
}

li:first-child button{
  background-color: yellow;
}
li:last-child button{
  background-color: crimson;
}

.deshabilitado{
  transition: all ease .3s;
}

.deshabilitado.tipo1{
  opacity: 0.6;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.deshabilitado.tipo2{
  position: relative;
}

.deshabilitado.tipo2::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.6)
}

.deshabilitado.tipo3{
  filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label tabindex="1" class="habilita">habilitar</label>
  <label tabindex="2" class="deshabilita">deshabilitar</label>
</div>
<h3>Normal</h3>
<ul>
  <li>
  <span>Texto ejemplo</span> <button>Boton</button>
  </li>
  <li>
  <span>Texto ejemplo</span> <button>Boton</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<h3>Disabilitado Ej: 1</h3>
<ul class="tipo1">
  <li>
  <span>Texto ejemplo</span> <button>Boton</button>
  </li>
  <li>
  <span>Texto ejemplo</span> <button>Boton</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<h3>Disabilitado Ej: 2 con seudoelemento</h3>
<ul class="tipo2">
  <li>
  <span>Texto ejemplo</span> <button>Boton</button>
  </li>
  <li>
  <span>Texto ejemplo</span> <button>Boton</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<h3>Disabilitado Ej: 3 combinado</h3>
<ul class="tipo1 tipo2 tipo3">
  <li>
  <span>Texto ejemplo</span> <button>Boton</button>
  </li>
  <li>
  <span>Texto ejemplo</span> <button>Boton</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Excelente solo una duda, estoy usando este `$("ul").toggleClass("deshabilitado");` para "apagar" la lista, pero como hago desde otro boton para "encender" la lista, me perdi en el ejemplo

Comment: **`toggleClass`** es para cuando usas un solo "botón", para cuando uses dos botones, recomiendo que uses **`addClass`** para añadir la clase que deshabilita y en el segundo botón usa **`removeClass`**.

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta con más código al final, para que veas un ejemplo con dos botones. Me cuentas.

Answer (score 1):

Debes agregar la clase *list_of_items* a tus botones, como se muestra en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<input type="button" class="list_of_items " value="Editar">
<input type="button" class="list_of_items " value="Borrar">
```

Al correr el script jquery encontrara aquellos elementos que posean esta clase los deshabilitará.